# Routes not found in flutter Login Form during onPressed action

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have created a signup form and login form with Routes called ChatPage.id and using pushNamed function to change the screen but on Pressing action the user is created on Firebase but I didnt get screen changing and the error generate is:

```
I/flutter (14603): Could not find a generator for route RouteSettings("/chatpage", null) in the _WidgetsAppState.
I/flutter (14603): Generators for routes are searched for in the following order:
I/flutter (14603):  1. For the "/" route, the "home" property, if non-null, is used.
I/flutter (14603):  2. Otherwise, the "routes" table is used, if it has an entry for the route.
I/flutter (14603):  3. Otherwise, onGenerateRoute is called. It should return a non-null value for any valid route not handled by "home" and "routes".
I/flutter (14603):  4. Finally if all else fails onUnknownRoute is called.
I/flutter (14603): Unfortunately, onUnknownRoute was not set.
```

this is my code:

```
class RegistrationScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String id = 'registration_screen';

  @override
  _RegistrationScreenState createState() => _RegistrationScreenState();
}

class _RegistrationScreenState extends State<RegistrationScreen> {

  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  final _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  bool showSpinner = false;
  String
      name,
      lastName,
      email,
      password;

  final databaseReference = Firestore.instance;

  bool rememberMe = false;
  bool showErrorMessage = false;

  void createRecord() async {
    await databaseReference.collection("user")
        .add({
      'name': '$name',
      'lastName': '$lastName',
      'email': '$email',
      'password': 'password',

    }).then((value) {
      print(value.documentID);
    });
  }
and the action:

onPressed: rememberMe ? () async {
                          try {
                            final newUser =
                            await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
                                email: email, password: password);
                            if (newUser != null) {
                              Navigator.pushNamed(context, ChatPage.id);
                            }
```

if I used pushReplacement it works but I can add ID to the ChatPage

Comment: Have you checked the answer?

Comment: Yes I am still working to fix it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error means the `route` is not found, you need to first define the routes example:

```
    initialRoute: '/',
    routes: {
      // When navigating to the "/" route, build the FirstScreen widget.
      '/': (context) => FirstScreen(),
      // When navigating to the "/second" route, build the SecondScreen widget.
      '/second': (context) => SecondScreen(),
    },
```

Then you need to use the name of the `route` in `pushNamed`, if you want to pass arguments also then you can use the property `argument` to send the arguments to the second screen:

```
          onPressed: () {
            // Navigate to the second screen using a named route.
            Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/second', arguments: "test");
          },
```

In `SecondScreen()` you can receive the argument:

```
class SecondScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     var arguments = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;
    print(arguments);
    return Scaffold(
    //...
```

https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/named-routes

https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/navigate-with-arguments